why my vite config(optimizedeps.include) is not working?
EDIT: I have create a minimal reproduction, please check this
For some reasons, I have to copy github:event-source's code to my own vite project and use it. I download the code and put it in 'src/utils/eventsource/index.js', and set my vite.config.js like following
export default defineConfig({
  build: {
    commonjsOptions: {
      include: [/src\/utils\/eventsource\/index.js/, /node_modules/],
    },
  },
  optimizeDeps: {
    include: ['src/utils/eventsource/index.js'],
  },
});

I tried import this module by 3 ways and start a dev server:

import { EventSourcePolyfill } from '../utils/eventsource': an error will be printed in the console: Uncaught SyntaxError: The requested module '/src/utils/eventsource/index.js' does not provide an export named 'EventSourcePolyfill'
import * as eventsource from '../utils/eventsource';: works well but when I use const { EventSourcePolyfill, NativeEventSource, EventSource } = eventsource; to get EventSourcePolyfill, NativeEventSource,and EventSource and print them in console, they are all undefined
import eventsource from '../utils/eventsource';: The same error as first way's is printed



The question lacks https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve . The error suggests you imported it as import { EventSourcePolyfill } from 'eventsource', which would be a mistake for CJS module

@Estus That's the way I import it. Is it incorrect? Why does it work well when I run vite build

Because vite dev and build have different toolchains, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/79169159/3731501 for the opposite problem. You need to import cjs modules as default import and then destructure it if necessary. Please, provide a way to reproduce the problem, the question originally stated that you use "eventsource" dep but then it appears as local module you didn't show. It's unclear why you used optimizeDeps and commonjsOptions for it, generally this shouldn't be done, this could be xy problem

@EstusFlask The way you mentioned not work for me

@EstusFlask I have edited the question to make it more clear

It should be import eventsource from '../utils/eventsource'; let {EventSourcePolyfill} = eventsource. It can't cause does not provide an export named 'EventSourcePolyfill' error because it uses "default" export. If there's a different one, please, provide it

@EstusFlask I have created a  minimal reproduction, please check it

Vite dev and build have different toolchains (esbuild and Rollup), it's common for them to work differently. CommonJS modules are supposed to be imported as default in ES modules, so regardless of the configuration the correct way to use it is:
import eventsource from '...'
const {EventSourcePolyfill} = eventsource

optimizeDeps.include and build.commonjsOptions.include options may work for NPM packages but may not work for local modules.
This can be fixed by using local dependency and npm i:
  "dependencies": {
    "eventsource": "file:./src/utils/eventsource"
  }

This also requires to create dummy package.json file in src/utils/eventsource in order for it to be processed as a package, then it can be imported as eventsource.
Similarly, resolve.alias can be used in Vite configuration for the same purpose, this doesn't require extra package.json:
import { fileURLToPath, URL } from "url";
...
resolve: {
  alias: {
    "eventsource": fileURLToPath(new URL("./src", import.meta.url)) + '/utils/eventsource/index.js',
  }
},

Alternatively, Vite CommonJS plugin could be used (not to be confused with Rollup plugin that uses build.commonjsOptions.include):
import { defineConfig } from 'vite';
import commonjs from 'vite-plugin-commonjs'

export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [
    commonjs({
      filter(id) {
        return id.match(/[\/]src[\/]utils[\/]eventsource[\/]index.js/)
      }
      ...

Alternatively, the module could be rewritten as ESM instead of CJS/UMD with only few changes.
The following UMD wrapper:
(function (global) {
  "use strict";

  ...

  (function (factory) {
    if (typeof module === "object" && typeof module.exports === "object") {
      var v = factory(exports);
      if (v !== undefined) module.exports = v;
    }
    else if (typeof define === "function" && define.amd) {
      define(["exports"], factory);
    }
    else {
      factory(global);
    }
  })(function (exports) {
    exports.EventSourcePolyfill = EventSourcePolyfill;
    exports.NativeEventSource = NativeEventSource;
    exports.EventSource = R;
  });
}(typeof globalThis === 'undefined' ? (typeof window !== 'undefined' ? window : typeof self !== 'undefined' ? self : this) : globalThis));

Is replaced with :
export default (function (global) {
  "use strict";

  ...

  return {
    EventSourcePolyfill;
    NativeEventSource;
    EventSource: R;
  };
})(globalThis);


The first way still not works. But using vite-plugin-commonjs or rewriting this module as an ESM both work! Thanks a lot!

You're welcome. I can confirm resolve.alias to work too, but esm conversion is simple and straightforward

You're right,  esm conversion is simple and straightforward.
But resolve.alias still not works. Can you modify my minimal reproduction to make it right? I don't know why it doesn't work in my code

https://stackblitz.com/edit/vitejs-vite-mobfyd72 Both file: and resolve.alias need to be used together with optimizeDeps.include and build.commonjsOptions.include. What you originally tried is how it's usually done, just won't work for local src/ imports in "dev" aka esbuild

Thanks a lot again! You teach me a lot!

this work to me
import {join} from "path"

export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [
    vue(),
    createHtmlPlugin({
      minify: true,
      inject: {
        data: {
          title: 'chat-webview',
        },
      },
    }),
  ],
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      '@': join(__dirname, "./src"),
    },
  },
  build: {
    rollupOptions: {
      input: 'index.html',
    },
    commonjsOptions: {
      include: [/src\/utils\/eventsource\/index.js/, /node_modules/],
    },
  },
  optimizeDeps: {
    include: ['src/utils/eventsource/index.js'],
  },
  css: {
    preprocessorOptions: {
      less: {},
    },
  },
});

File
import module from "@/utils/eventsource"


Please check the minimal reproduction in my question, that does not work
